# how can i remove fields with prefix for ABC:DEF.1 ABC:DEF.2 ABC:DEF.3 using mutate or any logstash filter

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, grok, logstash-grok

We trying to remove/convert/replace fields with prefix ABC:DEF.

Logstash.conf

```
filter {
 mutate {
 remove_field => [ "ABC:DEF_%{}" , "message" ]

 }
}
```

But the above filter is not working, message field is removed in the logs but the one which is having prefix ABC:DEF is as is.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27395554/remove-field-from-event-by-pattern.

Comment: @MagnusBäck Thanks Magnus, voted +1 for answer, thanks again