# Remove fields by their name pattern

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

We currently are using logstash with elasticsearch to log some of out application events. 
some of event holds fields that are dynamically named.
We want to apply a filter that will removed or merged them before entering to elasticsearch.
for example :

```
{  
  "Root": {  
    "EventType": "Info",  
    "Timestamp": 20150713153757.758  
  },  
  "Event": {  
    "Message": "itemsViews Created in 1 mSec",  
    "Cache_11542": true,  
    "Cache_10242": false,  
    "Cache_55240": 124  
  }  
}
```

In this case we would like to remove all the fields starting with "Cache_" under the object Event.

so the output to elasticsearch will be

```
{  
  "Root": {  
    "EventType": "Info",  
    "Timestamp": 20150713153757.758  
  },  
  "Event": {  
    "Message": "itemsViews Created in 1 mSec"
  }  
}
```

Is there a way to define a filler in the logstash configuration file to achieve this ?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: While this _question_ isn't a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27395554/remove-field-from-event-by-pattern/27396056#27396056, one of the answers happens to answer this question too.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looks like the [Ruby filter solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27395554/remove-field-from-event-by-pattern/27396056#27396056) that @magnus-bäck points out might be your solution. I had originally suggested the the [mutate filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html) using the "remove_field" array in conjunction with the gsub filter. Gsub to regex match your Cache* fields that can then be renamed into a variable for use in mutate. However, since you have n-number of Cache fields, I like the ruby script better. :)

Comment: Yes, but that parameter doesn't support wildcards which the OP needs since the fields are dynamically named.

Comment: The mutate documentation clearly states (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-remove_field) that it supports dynamic fields. It doesnt however, support regex there. Wondering if you could use gsub to apply the regex pattern to the field you want to remove. So "Cache_12345 --> delete_this_field". Then have mutate remove it? Honestly haven't tried but seems feasible.

Comment: What is meant by dynamic field in that context is simply that the filter supports `%{varname}` interpolation in each field name specification, like in the example of `foo_%{somefield}`. Wildcards or regexps aren't supported.

Comment: Yes I understand that. However, like I said, you could use gsub to replace the field with a regex match and a new field name. BUT you are right... the ruby filter answer is legit. You can replace the field names with gsub but you have n-number of dynamic fields...no way to know when the sequence ends.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to resolve this by the following code : filter { ruby { code => " if event['Event'] != nil event['Event'].to_hash.keys.each do |k| if k =~ /Cache_.*/ event['Event'].remove(k) end end end " } }