# Logstash remove fields by regex

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I'm using a [FIX filter plugin](https://github.com/connamara/logstash-filter-fix_protocol) to process some of our FIX logs. In those messages we receive multiple custom fields.  This is outside of the grok filter.  **I pass the message I care about into this secondary fix plugin**

Some of our messages for example look like this:

```
  "unknown_fields" => [
    [0] "5000",
    [1] "9723",
  ],
  "5000" => "FOOBARVAL",
  "9723" => "BAZBOOHUM",
  "IDSource" => "RIC_CODE",
```

### Question

Is there a way that I can remove tags with `mutate` or some other filter based on a regular expression(`^\d+$`)?

More specifically, is there a way that I can remove all of the integer fields that I know will be custom FIX fields (eg. 5000)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I appreciate the other answer, but I ended up using the `prune` filter plugin.

```
prune {
    blacklist_names => ["[0-9]+", "unknown_fields", "tags"]
}
```

Comment: TIL about prune :)

Answer (score 1):

This answer is very similar to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27396056/2785358

You can do something like this to match a regex:

```
filter {
  ruby {
    code => "
      event.to_hash.keys.each { |k|
        if k.match(/^\d+$/
          event.remove(k)
        end
      }"
  }
}
```